# How can I add element from my express server to my html table?

Tags: javascript, html, express, express-session

I want to add an element from server.js using express to my table in my html file. I know you can use double curly braces like "`{{example}}`" in the html file to import a value from the server file using `res.render(views, options)`. But I wonder if there is a way to add a new row to a table like this :

index.html :

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Adress</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{description}}</td>
        <td>{{adress}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

which add a new row everytime I call my `res.render()` method. Here what I have in my server file :

server.js :

```
app.get('/index', (req, res) => {
    var values = []
    var cursor = dbo.collection('collection').find()
    cursor.forEach(function (doc, err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        values.push(doc.name);
        values.push(doc.adress)
    }, function () {
        res.render('index', {description: values[0], adress: values[1]})
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Express is a backend server which can set the value in the page to be pushed to front end.
To add new rows to a rendered html at Front End , please use a combination of AJAX / Javascript

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `ejs` templating engine supports Javascript statements like the `cursor.forEach` in the template. Look, for example, at the `<ul>` example on the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs).